# NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3' error using Selenium on MAC

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver, urllib3, libressl

I am trying to open a website with selenium, currently trying with youtube. However when I run my program it takes ages for it load the website. I ran the same code on my windows pc but there I had no problems.

I have a good and stable internet connection. Still I receive a warning which follows as:

```
NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
```

however I am not certain if this is what's causing it to be so slow.

Any ideas what's causing it to be so slow?

I tried fixing the ssl warning with doing things written on reddit, but to no avail.

This is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

Comment: Hard to tell, your code works fine on my MacBook (M1). Takes maybe 2 seconds to open. You can try reinstall selenium or try `pip install -U selenium` to update it

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
```

...implies that the [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) system is using [urllib3](/questions/tagged/urllib3) ***v2.0*** where as the system Python's `ssl` module is compiled with **`LibreSSL 2.8.3`**.

But `LibreSSL` support in *urllib3 v2.0* have been removed which makes it impossible to be used with the system Python on in MAC OSX.

However the PR [Allow alternative SSL libaries with a warning](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/3024) addresses the issue and shouldn't impact the performance anymore.

---

### Solution

Install the latest version of ***urllib3***

---

### tl; dr

[urllib3>=2.0 does not work with system Python on macOS](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020)